# R - db connection function

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to create function for dbplyr connection, this connection I call this way.

```
tbl("connection"), in_schema("schema", "table") %>%
collect()
```

I created function

```
loadData <- 
    function(tbl_name) {
      result <- tbl("connection"), in_schema("usa", tbl_name)
      return(result)

    }
```

I call it this way

```
test <- loadData(tbl_name = "sales") %>% collect()
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Error in return(tbl("connection"), in_schema("usa", tbl_name)) : 
  multi-argument returns are not permitted
In addition: Warning message:
In mget(objectNames, envir = ns, inherits = TRUE) :
  strings not representable in native encoding will be translated to UTF-8
```

Is there a way how to call all my connection via similar function?

Comment: The problem is that your return statement has two arguments. You can only return one object from a function. What do you want this function 'loadData' to return?

Comment: Also, are `get_table` and `loadData` supposed to be the same function?

Comment: `result <- tbl(...), in_schema(...)` is not valid R syntax. What do you think should be happening here? What is your real code (assuming that I'm correct and that this is a parsing error)?

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to save some lines of code and do not write tbl("connection"), in_schema("schema", "table") all over again. So I created function where only table name will be called via nvariwble. Rest is always the same.